# how to get the path of download directory in maui?

Tags: maui

```
string location = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "Download", "abc.jpg");
image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(location);
```

Comment: Do you want the system Downloads folder, or your app's Downloads folder?

Comment: system download folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your download path of the `location` is equivalent to below:

**Windows:**

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\{GUID}_{hash}\LocalState\Download
```

**Android:**

```
/data/user/0/your_appliactionID/files/Download
```

**iOS\macOS:**

Returns the [Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) directory that is backed up by iTunes and iCloud.

Official reference link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=android

Comment: and Android, ios?

Comment: @EhabSaber, see my update.